# How to implement/debug a sensor driver in ANDROID

Tags: android, device-driver, linux-device-driver, sensors

Does anyone know of a walk-through or any examples of any code to setup sensors in android.

I have the drivers available to me.

Also i have implemented the sensors library as instructed
in the Android-Reference along the sensors.h template.

I am still unable to get any response at the apps level.

How do i trace this issue? what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE:**

**Jorgesys**'s link below points to a great APP to test if the sensor drivers are functioning properly or not.

Now that i know they are not functioning, Any ideas of on where to dig??...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found **everything** needed to get started [**developing Android sensor**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/index.html) apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cool [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/03/sensors.html).

You can check out this project too!

[Sensor Simulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator)

And the simulation of this project [here](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/6).